# como confeccionar un archivo php.ini

Tags: php7

estoy instalando en mis hosting la aplicacion joomla version 4.1.3 y no tiene php.ini para poder cambiar unos parametros que necesito. El problema esta en que se cambiarlos pero no se hacer un php.ini. Alguien podria echarme una mano? Tambien que me digan donde se pone para que funcione. Mil gracias a tod@s

Comment: Debes preguntarlo en tu hosting. No todos permiten el uso de php.ini personalizados según como esten corriendo el apache y el php. Si te dicen que vale, que lo pongas en determinada carpeta (normalmente la public), es simplemente un archivo de texto de directivas que empieza por una simple linea que contiene `[PHP]` y el resto de lineas son del tipo `directrices=datos`.  Normalmente los php.ini personalizados no deben contener todos los parámetros, sino simplemente los que quieres modificar del php.ini global de tu servidor. [Enlace con más info](https://www.php.net/es/configuration.file)

Answer (score 0):

El fichero php.ini es el archivo de configuración principal en PHP. Por lo que si tines php instalado tienes este archivo.

Por otro lado no se en que hosting estas trabajando pero normalmente los hosting tienen alguna opción para cambiar los parámetros de ese php.ini. Si no la encuentras ponte en contacto con el proovedor.

Por el contrario si tienes acceso al servidor podrias averiguar donde se encuentra el fichero php.ini creando un fichero .php en el Document Root de tu servidor con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Cuando abras el navegador con la ip o el dominio deberías poder ver la salida de phpinfo() donde encontrarás la "Configuration File (php.ini) Path", la cual indica la ruta predeterminada del archivo php.ini en tu sistema.